# SQL request return attribut with recent date and another field

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I want to get the value of  inventory field that has a specific designation and the latest date of that designation, for example if I have

```
    designation | Inventory | date
-----------------------------------------
    dufaston    | 20        | 15.05.2015
    dufaston    | 10        | 16.05.2015
    aspigic     | 5         | 17.05.2015
```

it should get me inventory = 10 for dufaston designation, but my sql code does not work, my code returns 0 because it takes me the most recent date of my table and is 17.05.2015 and which corresponds to aspigic not dufaston, here who can help me correcting my code

```
ResultSet  sqlCalcul=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT inventaire FROM calcul WHERE designation='"+designation+"' AND date=(SELECT MAX(date)  FROM calcul)");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your column `date` is an actual date field and not just a string representing a date?

If so, the following should work:

```
SELECT Inventory FROM your_table
    WHERE designation = your_designation
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

You basically select all rows that have the requested designation, order them by date and discard all but the most recent one.